# How to implement number field in swift programming?

Tags: swift2

How to implement number field in swift programming? There are only TextField in xcode palette.

Thanks,

Comment: select textfield -> Attribute Inspector ->Keyboard type -> number pad

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use **Int**, like so:

```
var someNumber: Int // mutable variable
let anotherNumber: Int // immutable constant
```

Does this help?

Comment: My problem fixed via coment of El Captain. Thank you for your answer,